# Faster Way to change pixels than SetPixel()

Tags: c++, c, windows, desktop, pixel

I have been trying to use SetPixelV for windows to display an image directly on the screen, as I am sure you know it is unbearably slow, and too slow for what I wan't to use it for. Could anyone point me in the right direction of how to Display Directly to the Screen (not in a window) that is faster the SetPixelV? (Does not have to be platform-independent)

Comment: You always have to draw to a window - the desktop itself is a window.

Comment: Read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183562%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN (especially the last paragraph).

Comment: @MarkRansom: that's a strange way to look at it.  There is a window handle that represents the desktop, but that doesn't prevent you from drawing "directly" to the "screen".  You can get a device context to the screen or display device and draw directly to that using the device context functions, including `BitBlt()`.

Comment: @AndréCaron, I had always assumed that GetDC(NULL) just returned a DC for the desktop. I Just played with Spy++ and discovered that the truth is a little more complicated, so I take back what I said.

Comment: @MarkRansom: you can also use `CreateDC()` to get a DC for a specific display device.  To date, I've never found a single document that clearly explains all the subtleties in the hierarchy (or at least, which elements are built on top of which others), but there is definitely "direct" (virtual) device/adapter access.  In any case, display devices seem to be at a lower layer than windows.

Comment: @AndréCaron: A DC is an abstract implementation of either a display device or an in-memory DC provided by NtGdi. Every HWND has an associated memory-DC (unless it's a fullscreen app like a movie, in which case it'll be a device-DC) that they can draw to and the DWM will composit all of the DCs together to give you the picture that you see on your screen. HWNDs are provided by NtUser which sits on top of NtGdi.

Comment: Despite all this talk about how to access the virtual screen device, I don't think that's what this question is about. The question starts out with the premise that `SetPixelV` *already* accomplishes the intended goal to "display an image directly on the screen." The question is about the speed, not the destination.

Answer (score 6):

You can build up your image in memory and use [`SetDIBitsToDevice`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162974.aspx) to copy it.

Answer (score 3):

You could call [`BitBlt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183370.aspx). That's assuming you already have the whole image — it doesn't set individual pixels (unless you blit a bunch of one-pixel images, but then you'd probably be in a worse position than where you started, speed-wise).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [BitBlit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is what you're looking for.